# saving & updating full json document with Spring data MongoTemplate

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

I'm using Spring data MongoTemplate to manage mongo operations. I'm trying to save & update json full documents (using String.class in java).

Example:

```
String content = "{MyId": "1","code":"UG","variables":[1,2,3,4,5]}";
String updatedContent = "{MyId": "1","code":"XX","variables":[6,7,8,9,10]}";
```

I know that I can update code & variables independently using:

```
Query query = new Query(where("MyId").is("1"));

Update update1 = new Update().set("code", "XX");
getMongoTemplate().upsert(query, update1, collectionId);

Update update2 = new Update().set("variables", "[6,7,8,9,10]");
getMongoTemplate().upsert(query, update2, collectionId);
```

But due to our application architecture, it could be more useful for us to directly replace the full object. As I know:

```
getMongoTemplate().save(content,collectionId) 
getMongoTemplate().save(updatedContent,collectionId)
```

implements saveOrUpdate functionality, but this creates two objects, do not update anything.

I'm missing something? Any approach? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use Following Code :

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("MyId").is("1"));

Update update = new Update();
Iterator<String> iterator = json.keys();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator.next();
    if(!key.equals("MyId")) {
        Object value = json.get(key);
        update.set(key, value);
    }
}


mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, entityClass);
```

There may be some other way to get `keyset` from json, you can use according to your convenience.

You can use `BasicDbObject` to get `keyset`.

you can get `BasicDbObject` using `mongoTemplate.getConverter()`.

Comment: Could you please explain more what's the json.keys() method?

Comment: `json.keys()` will give you fileds of your class.